# Bind ComboBox in DataGrid to collection in view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a view that is bound to my usercontrol. On my usercontrol I have a datagrid which is bound to a collection from my view. One column in that datagrid is a DataGridComboBoxColumn and I need to bind it to a different collection in my view. The binding of the datagrid looks like this:

```
DataContext="{Binding .}" ItemsSource="{Binding VictimVillages}"
```

The datacontext is the view and `VictimVillages` is the collection I want to display in the datagrid.

I have tried to access the collection I want to display in the combobox with

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Patterns,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Views:ViewPlanner}}}"
```

The name of the collection is Patterns, the type of the view is "ViewPlanner", which is in the `Views` namespace.

I have create a diagram of the dependencies. I need help to figure out the yellow part.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

when using RelativeSource Binding you(mostly) have to use **DataContext.YourProperty** in your Binding Path.

if your datacontext from the DataGrid also have the Patterns Collection you can do this

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Patterns,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
```

i often use "MarkerInterface" for Relative bindings. that mean empty interfaces that i can add to my views.

```
public interface IDataContextMarker4PatternCollection {}
```

now add this interface to your view/usercontrol where the Pattern Collection Property is in the Datacontext.

and now you can simply use RelativeSourceBinding

```
 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Patterns,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:IDataContextMarker4PatternCollection }}}"
```

Comment: The datacontext of the grid does know about the Patterns Collection, but the code you suggested does not work...

Comment: I gave up. I just gave the column a name and set the itemssource in the .cs file.